# How to list the taxonomy terms that fit the custom query?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Can't seem to find an answer to this on the web so I'm trying here...

I'm running a custom query where I return all the recipes that match specific ingredients (custom taxonomy used here).

```
$ingredients = array('poulet', 'oignon', 'piment', 'tomate');
$type = 'souper';

$args = array(
  'post_type'    => 'recipe',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'main_ingredient',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $ingredients,
        'operator' => 'IN'
    )
  ),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

What I need to do then is to list, for each recipe, all ingredients that bring the recipe in this list.

For example, if a recipe has "poulet", "champignon", "lait" and "tomate" as ingredients, I want to see a simple ul/li list that includes "poulet" and "tomate", because these two where requested in the query and match the ingredients of this recipe.

Can someone help me please ? I have completely no idea where to start.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get this recipe's assigned terms (recipe having `$recipe_id`):

```
$terms_arr = [];
$terms_objs = get_the_terms($recipe_id, 'main_ingredient');
if ($terms_objs) {
    foreach ($terms_objs as $term_obj) {
        $terms_arr[] = $term_obj->slug;
    }
}
```

Find the terms found in both arrays:

```
$the_ingrediens = array_intersect($ingredients, $terms_arr);
```